# Truth values for 2 implications and whether or not they imply each other

Tags: logic

Let *A, B, C*, and *D* be arbitrary statements.

Consider the following implications:

> 1. $\text{If $A$ and $B$, then $C$ or $D$}$
> 2. $\text{If $A$, then $D$}$

**Question:**

- Suppose that (1) is true. Is it possible that A is true but both C and D are false?
- Do either of the statements imply the other?

I'm not quite sure how to start off the solution for this problem. I considered a truth table, but I wasn't sure how A and B would form the truth values for C or D. Can anyone explain to me how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**a.** Yes. Since C and D are false, the conclusion of Statement 1 is false. But Statement 1 is true, so it must be the case that the hypothesis of Statement 1 is false. Since A is true yet A and B is false, it must be the case that B is false. So the situation is possible, but only when B is false.

**b.** Case 1: Statement 1 imply Statement 2: No. Let A and B both be $3 < 4$, let C be $2\ge1$, and let D be $2 < 1$. Statement 1 is true, but Statement 2 If $3 < 4$, then $2 < 1$ is false.
Case 2: Statement 2 imply Statement 1: Yes. Assume Statement 2 is true. To prove that Statement 1 is true, we need to assume that the hypothesis of Statement 1 is true, namely A and B . Therefore, both A and B are true. Since A is true and Statement 1 is true, it follows that D is true. Since D is true, C or D is true. Hence Statement 1 is true.

Comment: Is there any way to show part a in a truth table?

Comment: Yes there is. It is very simple from what I have shown. But I will leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

> Statement 1 If A and B, the C or D
>
> Statement 2 If A, then D

This is: $1: (A\wedge B)\to(C\vee D)\\2: (A\to D)$

By Material Implication Equivalence: $1': (\neg A\vee \neg B\vee C\vee D)\\2': (\neg A\vee D)$

> a) Suppose that Statement 1 is true. Is it possible that A is true but both C and D are false?

Yes, since either $C$ *or* $D$ are true whenever both $A$ and $B$ are true, we can have that possiblity happen when $B$ is false.  $(\top\vee \bot)\to(\bot\wedge\bot) = \top$

> b) Do either of the statements imply the other?

As above, statement 1 can be satisfied when $D$ is false and $A$ is true, so it does not imply statement 2, which is that $D$ is true whenever $A$ is.

However, every way to satisfy statement 2 satisfies statement 1.  Statement 2 is satisfied when either A is false or D is true.  If A is false then statement 1 is satisfied, and if D is true then statement 1 is satisfied.  Therefore statement 1 is true whenever statement 2 is true.  That's an implication.

( Alternately we can immediately see that statement 2' implies statement 1' by disjunction introduction. )

$$(A\to D) \vdash (A\wedge B)\to (C\vee D) \\\qquad\Box$$

If $D$ is true whenever $A$ is true, then either $C$ or $D$ is true whenever both $A$ and $B$ are true.